# Apple 2015 MacBook Pro not booting

Tags: boot, mac, macbook-pro, macos-mojave

I have an issue since this morning. My machine didn't boot, my machine battery is charged, it shows me the screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfNi2.jpg):

[image: Mac Screen Image after Boot]

I have tried everything explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVDF4WyKvVs).

- SCM
- Safe Mode
- NVRAM

Comment: That's a clear indication of a corrupted system. Try Recovery or Time Machine. If still no joy, then Internet Recovery.

Comment: well what i have done i have reinstalled the software.